# Find all degree solutions in the interval 0° ≤ θ < 360°.

Tags: trigonometry

Any help with this would be highly appreciated! Tried this problem several times but kept getting the wrong answers!

Find all degree solutions in the interval $0° ≤ θ < 360°$. If rounding is necessary, round to the nearest tenth of a degree. Use your graphing calculator to verify the solution graphically. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

$$10 \sin^2 θ − 9 \cos 2θ = 0$$

Comment: Oh it reads like $10\sin^2\theta-9\cos 2\theta=0$, is that right? Then you can express $\cos 2\theta$ in terms of $\sin^2 \theta$ and get a linear equation of $\sin^2 \theta$ then.

Comment: OP wants a solution for $\tan  2 \theta=0.9?$

Comment: Please use proper formatting. Your equation is ambiguous. Is that $\sin^2 \theta$ or $\sin 2\theta$? And what about the other term, is that $\cos 2 \theta$?

Comment: it is sin ^2 0 my computer wouldnt let me type the other one and yes the other term is cos 20

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Rewrite $\sin^2 \theta$ as $1-\cos^2 \theta$ and $\cos 2 \theta$ as $2 \cos^2 \theta - 1$, then collect terms in $\cos^2 \theta$,

OR

Rewrite $\cos 2 \theta$ as $1- 2 \sin^2 \theta$, and collect terms in $\sin^2 \theta.$

Edit: You should get either $28 \sin^2 \theta - 9 = 0$ or $19-28 \cos^2 \theta =0$.  Solve either of these, and you should get $34.5^{\circ}, 145.5^{\circ}, 214.5^{\circ}, \text {and } 325.5^{\circ}$ as the answers.

Comment: Still getting the wrong answers? Did i do something wrong?

Comment: What are the answers you're getting?